# Seeking small bluetooth keyboard with Home/End/PageUp/PageDown keys

Tags: hardware-recommendation, keyboard

Seeking small bluetooth keyboard with Home/End/PageUp/PageDown keys that has same "feel" as [Apple wireless keyboard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184LL/B).  Found these:

1. [keyboard1](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823839002&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-NA-_-NA) (Apple-copy-cat silver, which I like)
2. [keyboard2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00653P3K8) (regular black, not as aesthetically pleasing)

Any experience with the keystroke quality/feel (for above or other offerings)?  Compared to the Apple wireless/bluetooth keyboard?  How about bluetooth-connection quality to a MacBook Pro/Air?

Love the keystroke feel + overall design/aesthetics of aforementioned [Apple wireless keyboard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184LL/B)--but it doesn't have the aforementioned keys, which I need to be in my comfort zone in "Microsoft Excel power user" mode, among a few other things.  Yes, am aware of key remapping, but too cumbersome and hard for muscle-memory to remember.

Answer (score 1):

The fn key + up/down/left/right arrows give you that functionality on the Apple keyboard. Earlier iterations of Apple keyboards were labeled as such but it still works on the newer unlabeled ones.

Comment: Thx.  And yes, familiar with these mappings.  But said mappings are both hard for my "muscle memory" to remember and are often not consistent across operational/application context (eg, operate diff from one app to the next).  Thus explicit home/end/pgup/pgdn keys strongly preferred.